# Using carrierwave to upload images as private on cloudinary from Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm working on a rails website that needs to upload image as private on Cloudinary. Now it's uploading image as public on Cloudinary.

I can manually upload files as private on Cloudinary with the command :

```
Cloudinary::Uploader.upload("Photo No. 11.jpeg", :type => :private)
```

The image become private and unreachable.

Is there a way to do it with Carrierwave ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be doing something like this in your uploader

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base  
  include Cloudinary::CarrierWave  
  make_private # This will make sure you're images are uploaded as private
  eager

  version :medium do    
    process :resize_to_fill => [164, 164, 'North']
    process :convert => 'jpg'
    cloudinary_transformation :quality => 80
  end
end
```